Tzaddik or Rasha: Correlation between human abilities and merits

"If you have learned much Torah, do not claim credit for yourself, because for such a purpose were you created.". Avot 2.8:


"And that angel takes the drop of semen from which a person will be formed and presents it before the Holy One, Blessed be He, and says before Him: Master of the Universe, what will be of this drop? Will the person fashioned from it be mighty or weak? Will he be clever or stupid? Will he be wealthy or poor?" Niddah 16.b

Recent neuro- and behavioral science appears to back those earlier Jewish sources concerning the strong correlation between individuals' genetics, epigenetics, and environmental factors and their behaviors. In other words, these elements significantly influence a person's decisions.
They imply that human free will (if exists), is quite limited, constrained by these factors.
If so, it would be reasonable to refrain from both criticizing the wicked (e.g. atheists or criminals) and praising the pious (renowned rabbis or Tzaddikim), as we cannot know which part of their behavior was "predetermined" in Heavens and what choice they had.
Is there a discussion of such a phenomenon in Rabbinic literature?

You omitted the next words from the quote from Nidda: ואילו רשע או צדיק לא קאמר

On praising the righteous see Metzudat David on Yeshayahu 3:10: שבחו ורוממו את הצדיק כי עשה את הטוב, כי הצדיקים יאכלו גמול מעשיהם, ולזה שבחוהו, למען ילמדו ממנו לטוב להם

@ba intentionally. If one studies Torah 24/7 because he was given proper intelligence, persistence, and determination, we cannot know whether this is his merit or what was/is expected.

Yes, Rabbi Levi Yitzchok of Berditchev produced much "Rabbinic literature" on the extreme lengths we should go to to never accuse a Jew, even to the point of denying our eyes. I saw it in the Chida, and many sichot recently too - there are many teachings that aid us in "refraining from criticizing", based on your points (and more). It would help this question a lot if you quote the sources that back up your paragraph about science

"If one studies Torah 24/7 because he was given proper intelligence, persistence, and determination".... then he still had the alternative to use that intelligence, persistence, and determination to learn something else, or to get involved in some other field of endeavor. (Some professional sportsplayers, to take one example, have those qualities too.) And that's what we should praise him for, and that's his merit - that he made the right choice.

Your question is mixing 2 important matters. 1. How a person should judge oneself (he was created for what he does and should not take pride). 2. How others should view one person's accomplishments. Certainly there is more positive attitude to for others.

@Meir Not exactly, being born into this environment one doesn't have a real "choice" to excel in quantum physics.

@YDJ You are right, But if one "מחזיק טובה לעצמו" all others do the same, they praise him for his achievements, which are/might be predetermined.

@AlBerko one should only מחזיק טובה לעצמו in the sense to inspire others and do what is right (as Hashem will repay in the world to come).  Not as a source for getting כבוד. Was not it the problem of Korach? Many predetermined achievements turned up being failures because people chose not to act, fight, continue.

If not quantum physics, then plenty of other areas of life outside of Torah. And yes, there's no environment that's 100% sealed off from the outside world, where a child might not find some other outlet for his talents and energies.

@Meir Many confuse possibility and probability. Like Pascal's wager: it's a 50/50 probability that God exists and a 50/50 chance of finding a million bucks on your bed. While you might hold that you have a choice to kill yourself in the next 5 minutes, the probability is nil.

A person is born with natural tendencies and predispositions towards certain actions. When these predispositions are negative, we call that the yetzer hara, evil inclination. The person is not bound by these predispositions, but is able to choose to do otherwise. This is called free choice.

@AlBerko And that has nothing whatsoever to do with the topic at hand. A child born and raised in the best Torah environment still has a lot more than a nil probability of using his talents for things other than full-time Torah study. Sadly, we see that they even have more than a nil probability of going off the derech entirely.

Free will is limited to subjects of issur v'heter. If it's not a matter relating to what the Torah commands or prohibits then it's not a matter of free will. Kosher vs not kosher is one example but what type of cuisine that is kosher is not.

@Dude How about choosing between two Mitzvos? Or two rabbis?

I recommend R EE Dessler's Qunterus haBechirah (Booklet on Free Will) in Michtav meiEliyahu (available in English in Strive for Truth). In it he talks about how true choice is only at the battlefront between truth and desire. Other decisions are made pre-consciously. And we are judged not by where we are, but by how our choices have moved that front. It's that last point that makes me think it answers your question. The links to the source I put at https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/68444/what-is-free-will-and-do-we-have-it/68484#68484 no longer work

The perspective of the Toras Haminchah (talmid of the Rashba) Parshas Matos seems to answer this:

וכשהנפש השכלית משתלחת לבוא להתקשר בחומר, שואלים לה שתבחר לה
הדרך שתחפוץ ותרצה בו דכתיב וכל צבאם, ודרשו חז״ל לצביונם נבראו,
פירוש לרצונם ולדעתם.
יש מהם שבחר להיות צדיק ועשיר כדי שיוכל לעמוד בצדקו… ושיעשה רצון קונו בעושר ההוא, והקב׳׳ה מוסרו למזל העושר והצדק להנהיגו באלו הדרכים ומזהירו שישמור עצמו מלחטוא, שאע״פ שנמסר למזל מ׳׳מ רשות ביד האדם להכריח המזל יותר ממה שיש רשות וכח במזל להכריחו, ועל זאת ההתראה הוא בא לעולם דכתיב ראה נתתי לפניך היום את החיים ואת הטוב ואת המות ואת הרע, אתן לפניך לא נאמר אלא נתתי כבר.
הרי זה האיש במעט התעורתת שיתעורר יהיה צדיק גמור שהמזל מצוה עליו להכין אותו ולסעדו, ונמצא שהוא צדיק וטוב לו. וקראו חכמי האומות לזה הצדיק ״צדיק מנוחה״ כלומר שאין לו טורח להדריך עצמו בדרכי הצדק וגם יש לו עושר. ואם יטה אשורו מיני דרך לא יאבד ממנו העושר ההוא כי הוא משתדל להוסיף הון והמזל עוזרו, אבל יענש לעולם הבא עונש גדול כפול שהרי כל מה ששאלו עיניו נתנו לו וברצונו חטא בלי הכרח נמצא רשע וטוב לו, ואם ילך ברע היושר זה צדיק
וטוב לו.
ויש שאינו חפץ להיות עשיר אלא צדיק ועני, כי אם יהיה עשיר שמא העושר
יסיתנו לכפור ביוצרו…
ויש שאינו חפץ להיות צדיק אלא רשע, כי הרוצה להיות צדיק ונמסר למזל הצדק אין לו כ״כ שבח כי זה עובד השם ית׳ מצד הטבע לא מצד ההכרח, וכבוד השם כשאדם מכתת את טבעו לעבודתו ובזה מתרבה כבודו, וע״כ הוא בוחר להיות רשע כדי שיכתת המזל לכבוד שמים… שאע״פ שבחר להיות רשע הרשות בידו להיות צדיק ועל זה הוא בוטח להיות שולט במזל…
ויש שאינו חפץ להיות עשיר אלא עני ורשע כמו שאמרנו למעלה וזהו רשע ורע לו, ואם יצדק עצמו יהיה צדיק ורע לו ושכרו כפול ומכופל על כולם. ולזה קוראים חכמי האמת ״צדיק תלאה״ כי יש לו טורח מצד טבעו ומצד עניותו.

The gist of it is that souls choose their tendencies before descending to the physical world. I would highly recommend reading it in full (the sefer is available on hebrewbooks.org).
I know this might not be a direct response to the question, but I felt this is fascinating and relevant enough to justify it.
Ksivah vachasimah tovah.

Thank you, I truly appreciate your effort. Are you familiar with Schopenhauer's "you can do what you want, but you can't want what you want"? Seemingly, acc. to Nidda 16b, God fashions the souls including their wants, a person does not choose to be rich or poor but your answer seems to contradict the Gemmora, don't you think?

I would assume the Toras Haminchah’s understanding of the gemara would be that Hashem fashions the person along with his desires, based on each souls preference. I don’t know that this choice of the soul can be considered free will. It’s possible that he addresses the gemara directly later on but I don’t remember.
